# Trigger Android Notifications when an action occurs in the database

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am attempting to trigger notifications to my users in my Android application when a certain change is made in the (Firebase) database. I am creating a ride sharing application, so when a match is found, or someone joins someones 'ride', or a 'ride' is modified, the users associated should get a notification letting them know.

The following code is what I currently have:

```
    private void scheduleNotification(int delay) {
    Notification notification = getNotification();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}

private Notification getNotification() {
    content = findMatches();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pu_train)
                    .setContentTitle("We have a ride match for you!")
                    .setContentText(content);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ShowRidesActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ShowRidesActivity.class);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    //mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    return mBuilder.build();
}
```

In the previous code, I am creating one of my notifications and then setting up the scheduling for that notification using alarmManager. AlarmManager then triggers my NotificationPublisher which looks like:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    if (ShowRidesActivity.matches.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ride>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ShowRidesActivity.matches) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return view;
            }
        };
        ShowRidesActivity.list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    if ((ShowRidesActivity.content) != null && CentralData.notifications)
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
```

I've looked on stackoverflow and googled around, but I can't find anything on how to get the notifications trigger on certain events (like changes in the database). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why you can't call notification method after database changes ?

Comment: Because I have to schedule the notification with the alarmManager, which takes an time interval to trigger the Notification Publisher Code, so I can't call the notification after database changes.